# Congratulations to DucatiKiller for reaching 20k Points!

Tags: discussion, congratulations

We've had a lot of congrats for @DucatiKiller over the past few months. This one is special. 20k is a milestone and you've reached it brother! Great job on making this site awesome!

Comment: Agreed - congratulations @DucatiKiller - and in not much more than a year too!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks guys.  The site has given back a lot to me so it's definitely a two way street.  Good peeps here and lots of knowledge.  I've learned quite a bit about the 4 wheelers here.  What are those things called?  Cars, I think.  Anyway, thanks @paulster2   Your the man.

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "cages"...